# How to make a function that replaces the exponent feature?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before hand yes this is a homework question. Well there are two I'd like to ask for help with. The first one is a function that needs to take two numbers (base, exp) and then multiply base by itself by the amount of times that exponent represents. eg. base = 2, exp = 3. it would be 2*2*2. So far this is what I have:

```
def iterPower(base, exp):

if base and exp <= 0:
    return("The answer is 0")
elif base and exp == 0:
    return("1")
else:
    for i in range(exp):
        ans = base * base
        return ans

print("iterPower(0, 0): should be 1 == "  \
     + str(iterPower(0, 0)))

print("iterPower(5, 3): should be 125 == "  \
     + str(iterPower(5,3)))

print("iterPower(-2.0, 3): should be -8.0 == "  \
     + str(iterPower(-2.0, 3)))
```

However when I run the above function. The first test gives me none, the second test gives me just 25, and the last test gives me 4.0. I ran the code itself through a code visualizer to see what's happening(or not happening) and I see that the range is not being utilized. I also notice that as I have it (base * base) would not give a correct answer either. I tried googling and going through the already answered questions here and I come up with nothing.

edit: I know there's a built in operator but the point of the assignment is to not use the operator. The paper practically has giant bold letters saying it's use is banned -,-

Comment: If `exp` is <0, it should be a decimal.

Comment: @AndrewL. we're not allowed to use the function for this.

Comment: You return on the first iteration?

Comment: @AndrewL. so I shift the return to the left. do I line it up with the else or do I line it up with the prints?

Comment: @AndrewL. at what point did I reassign it? I thought it was just assigned as base * base

Comment: @martineau it *should*, but was it in the OP's code?

Comment: @AndrewL. I already moved it out of the loop. and didn't the range deal with the changing it?

Comment: @AlexisNonya In your loop you always assign `base * base` to `ans`, so the only thing that matters for the value of `ans` is going to be the last iteration. `ans` will always be equal to `base * base` no matter how many iterations. You probably meant `ans = ans * base` so that each iteration adds one more multiplication by `base`.

Comment: @AlexisNonya Also, the first `elif` clause in your code will never execute because anything that could match `base and exp == 0` also matches the earlier `base and exp <= 0`.

Comment: @ToddKnarr I keep getting an error that tells me that the ans is referenced before assignment. I have it as

Comment: ans = base            
            ans = ans * base
    return ans

Comment: @ToddKnarr so it's useless?

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want:

```
ans = 1
for i in range(exp):
    ans *= base
return ans
```

As your last condition.
You also don't need the middle condition.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

```
def iterPower(base, exp):
    if base < 0:
        return 0
    ans = 1
    for i in range(exp):
        ans *= base
    return ans
```

First, check how the conditionals work in Python, `base and exp <= 0` is different than `base <= 0 and exp <= 0`.

Second, blocks in Python are defined accordingly to the indentation, so those two loops do different things:

```
for i in range(exp):
    ans *= base
    return ans

for i in range(exp):
    ans *= base
return ans
```

Third, `base * base` is constant if `base` doesn't change, with that in mind compare `ans = base * base` to `ans = ans * base`.

Comment: There's no reason to check for exp < 0.  Raising a negative number to a power is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help and taking time out to help me.. I've already gotten it working.

Comment: This code just handles non-negative integers exponents, a better implementation should throw an error otherwise.

@AlexisNonya, I think it's more important to understand why it was not working than get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Can also use a while loop to shorten your code.

```
def iterPower(base, exp):
    answer = 1
    while exp > 0:
        answer *= base
        exp -= 1
    return answer
```

Comment: The assignment did suggest using a while loop but for some reason I came up with a solution utilizing a for loop.

Comment: Yes.  I took this course a year ago.  I remember this problem.

Comment: The while loop will never terminate if the passed value of exp is less than or equal to zero.

Comment: You should really use a for-loop for this problem. You know exactly how many times you are going to loop.

Comment: Correct.  But if I recall correctly, the exercise assumes exp > 0.

Comment: really? from the same school? and thanks for the assistance.

Comment: actually the exp is random and some test cases are given, but the code asks me to put it in such a way to make it as if I don't know how many times it's supposed to loop. Not sure if that just made sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. The statement `if base and exp <= 0` basically translates to `if (base) and (exp <= 0)`. Here the conditions are evaluated separately. You may want to use `if base <= 0 and exp <= 0:` (or something similar).
2. The statement `ans = base * base` basically squares `base` and assigns the result into `ans`. Wouldn't `ans = ans * base` be better (ensure you initialize `ans` to 1 before you do that.
3. The return statement (`return ans`) is inside the for loop which means that the loop will only be executed once. You may want to put it outsdide the loop.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1I think the code you want is:

```
def iterPower( base, exp ):

    if base and exp < 0:
        return 0
    elif base and exp == 0:
        return 1
    elif base and exp == 1:
        return base
    else:
        ans = base
        for i in range( 1, exp ):
            ans *= base
        return ans
```

The modifications are:

- The function always returns an integer.
- Negative exponents return 0.
- An exponent of 0 returns 1.
- An exponent of 1 returns `base`.
- Exponents of 2 and greater multiply `base` by itself `exp` times.

Comment: Looks like your range is a bit off. It has to be `range(1, exp)` :)

Comment: Ah okay. I have taken note of this. Thank you for your help.